# H2o Packge Error: Cannot perform booster operation: updater is inactive on node /127.0.0.1:54321

Tags: python, h2o, xgboost

I am running xgboost using H2o package in python. I set to use all 32 cores of my machine. The classifier is inside a for loop to run the classification for different parameters. I am initiating the h2o and closing it in the loop. It runs for 2-3 round in the loop and returns back error "Cannot perform booster operation: updater is inactive on node /127.0.0.1:54321" for some runs. 
anyone has idea why I am getting such an error?

Thanks,
Elnaz

```
`for dates in start_end_dates:
     for window_size in window_sizes:
          print dates[0], dates[1], dates[2], window_size
          model_string = str(dates[0])+ '_'+ str(dates[1]) + ':'+ str(dates[2])+ ':'+ str(window_size)
    ## load daily transaction types 
         ## this function runs in parallel on all cpus 
         daily_transactions_type_df = transform_transactions_types.transform(dates[0], dates[1], window_size)
         ##load daily transactions
         ## this function runs in parallel on all cpus 
         daily_transactions_df = transfrom_daily_transactions.transform(dates[0], dates[1], window_size, max_number_of_instrument)

         snapshot_date = dates[1]
         ## user status list
         user_status_list = Classification_helpers.load_user_status_data_from_gbq(snapshot_date)
    user_status_list

         ## Normalize the data
         numeric_columns = daily_transactions_type_df.iloc[:,1:].columns.tolist()  
        other_columns = []
        daily_transactions_type_df_norm = Classification_helpers.normalize_data_without_outliers(daily_transactions_type_df, numeric_columns, other_columns)

        ## Normalize the data
        numeric_columns = daily_transactions_df.iloc[:,1:-6].columns.tolist()  
        other_columns = daily_transactions_df.iloc[:,-5:].columns.tolist()
        daily_transactions_df_norm =   Classification_helpers.normalize_data_without_outliers(daily_transactions_df,numeric_columns,other_columns)

        data_frames = [daily_transactions_type_df_norm,   daily_transactions_df_norm, user_status_list[['USER_ID', 'label']]]

        df = Classification_helpers.create_labelled_data(data_frames)
        numeric_columns = df.iloc[:,1:-6].columns.tolist()  
        other_columns = df.iloc[:,-6:-1].columns.tolist()  

        nthreads = -1
        Classification_helpers.init_h2o(nthreads)

         model, performance, predictions = Classification_helpers.train_XGboost(df, numeric_columns, other_columns, model_string)
    print performance.auc()`
```

Comment: Hi Eli, can you provide a reproducible code snippet that shows the code you ran right before you got your error message? Please also specify what version of H2O you are using and provide information about the environment you are running in. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for comment, I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: All the interesting things are happening in your `Classification_helpers` functions. :-)

Comment: :)))) That is set of functions, handles data transformations. I am using multiprocessing in python, opening and closing pool in each iterations. does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Watch the action using the Flow interface: http://127.0.0.1:54321, and pay attention to memory use.

See 
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html#viewing-cluster-status for the screen that you should be watching. You will see the amount of free memory on each node updating live.

---

Without any more information, one guess would be that you are running out of memory, because you are using more memory on each iteration of your for loop.

If so, it is hard to give advice without seeing what you are doing inside the for loop; but if the training data is the same, make sure that is loaded outside the for loop. In worst case, you should do the H2O init and shutdown within the for loop (and save your model at the end of each iteration, for later use).

Oh, one more possibility, as you didn't mention it: specify explicitly how much memory to give H2O, in your h2o.init() call. You might find you can get away with giving it more than whatever the default is. (But don't give H2O *all* the machine's memory, or everything will become unstable!)

Comment: Thanks, for reply. I have tested init and shutdown inside the loop. It still has problem. I have 64G of RAM and running H2O on python 2.7. I have attahhed the code in the question as well.

Comment: @Eli How does the cluster memory change over time? That is the key thing to watch, live, so that you know if low memory is causing the problem or something else.

Comment: I think, I found the problem. I am increasing the dimension of my dataset inside the loop, data size is (40000, 1000). I believe XGboost cannot handle that? do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But when you specify (example) `max_runtime_secs = 6000` there will be no error. That indicator solved my problem.

BTW, try changing parameters within `h2o.xgboost`, the problem is probably there.